# Cannot change Figma text font fill

Tags: text, fonts, figma

I was pressing the option key to duplicate an element and I did so a few times. Then, all the text elements on my project turned to a peculiar style with no-fill text, as you see in the picture.

[image]

The strange thing is, even when I create a new Figma project and I add a new text element, the same font persists. I can successfully change the font to another font family, and I can also change the style from Regular to another style. That changes the font family, but the text is always without a fill. I tried "Undo," and I undid the entire project to the initial point, but the strange font persists, which is strange and makes it look like a bug. How do I change the text to normal black text?

Answer (score 1):

I opened my Figma projects today, and the problem had been solved.